# How to reference a prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

```
public Gem gem;
public int coins;
public static SaveSystem instance {get;  private set;}
void Awake()
{
    coins = gem.LastCoins;
}
```

The "Gem" here means the Gem script and ofcourse the gems here are an prefabs , so how i can reference it in the inspector or in script

Comment: In general please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is in `c#`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more context, the solution would be to drag the Prefab from the 'Project' Tab into the 'gem' field in the Inspector of the object with the script attached.

Comment: then how i can accses the script

Comment: What script do you mean? The Gem script? Just for clarification, Prefabs are not scripts. Prefab objects can have scripts attached as components though.

Comment: I just figure it out, using GetComponent. thank you so much

Comment: @notoniichan you should be exposing a `GameObject prefab` member

Comment: @MickyD it's actually no necessary to always use `GameObject` for prefabs. `Instantiate` also works for the script reference on the prefab, and sometimes saves a `GetComponent` call.